# How to access method defined in a module inside another module in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, methods, module, include, nomethoderror

Given the following example:

```
module A
  module B
    def whoa
      puts 'Whoa!'
    end
  end
end
```

How can I access the **whoa** method?

```
1.9.3p392 :047 > A.B.whoa
NoMethodError: undefined method `B' for A:Module

1.9.3p392 :048 > A::B.whoa
NoMethodError: undefined method `whoa' for A::B:Module

1.9.3p392 :049 > A::B::whoa
NoMethodError: undefined method `whoa' for A::B:Module
```

None of these approaches seems to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you don't want class level methods, you can also include the module into a class, instantiate an object of that class and call `whoa`:

```
class C
   include A::B
end

c = C.new
c.whoa
# Whoa!
```

Answer (score 6):

You've define the method as an instance method.  If you want to use the method without an instance, it should be a class method on the module:

```
module A
  module B
    def self.whoa
      puts 'Whoa!'
    end
  end
end

1.9.3p327 :009 > A::B.whoa
Whoa!
 => nil
```